# Adding an image into a jQuery Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a jquery script that resizes a div with a map in it and when it does this the state of the div that has been clicked to perform the action changes and the text within changes also.

the initial state is an image:

```
 <div class="menu"><img src="../images/expand.png" width="20px" /></div>
```

Then when its clicked it removes the image and says the word 'Close' Then when you click Close it changes again to 'Open'

Heres is the jQuery:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$(".menu").on('click', function() {
    var state = $(this).data('state');
    if ( state ) {
        $("#googleMap").animate({height: 100 }, 800);
        state = false;
    }else{
        $("#googleMap").animate({height: 300 }, 800);
        state = true;
    }
    $(this).text(state ? 'Close' : 'Open');
    $(this).data('state', state);
});
});//]]>  

</script>
```

This is the line I'm trying to change:

```
$(this).text(state ? 'Close' : 'Open');
```

This is my failed attempt:

```
$(this).text(state ? '<img src="../images/shrink.png" width="20px" />' : '<img src="../images/expand.png" width="20px" />');
```

I've searched through google to find an answer to this, I know its something really really simple so was looking for a tip if anyone knows the best thing to do.

Comment: try with $(this).html(state ? '<img src="../images/shrink.png" width="20px" />' : '<img src="../images/expand.png" width="20px" />');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try like this,

```
if(state)
{
$(this).append('<img src="../images/shrink.png" width="20px" />');
}
else
{
$(this).append('<img src="../images/expand.png" width="20px" />');
}
```

Technically, [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) would replace the contents inside that particular tag. Not the Html. In order to to so you should use [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) or [.html().](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

Modified version of your code,

```
$(window).load(function(){
$(".menu").on('click', function() {
    var state = $(this).data('state');
    if ( state ) {
        $("#googleMap").animate({height: 100 }, 800);
        state = false;
    }else{
        $("#googleMap").animate({height: 300 }, 800);
        state = true;
    }

    $(this)
    .html(state ? '<img src="../images/shrink.png" width="20px" />' :
    '<img src="../images/expand.png" width="20px" />');

    //or maybe
    // $(this).append(state ? '<img src="../images/shrink.png" width="20px" />'
    // : '<img src="../images/expand.png" width="20px" />');

    $(this).data('state', state);

});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
$(this).text(state ? '<img src="../images/shrink.png" width="20px" />' : '<img src="../images/expand.png" width="20px" />');
```

to

```
$(this).append(state ? $('<img src="../images/shrink.png" width="20px" />') : $('<img src="../images/expand.png" width="20px" />'));
```

Refer [how append works](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).text(state ? '<img src="../images/shrink.png" width="20px" />' : '<img src="../images/expand.png" width="20px" />');
```

use html instead of text method like below

```
$(this).html(state ? '<img src="../images/shrink.png" width="20px" />' : '<img src="../images/expand.png" width="20px" />');
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing images with JS is quite unprofessional,
cause it's a **new request to the server for a new image** and there's a wait time for it.

I would

- Preload all the needed images first or
- Create a sprite and with JS just change the Sprite background-position or
- **Create a CSS ckeckbox, hide it, set a bg-image for `<label>`, and use the `:checked` property to change the label background position and even toggle the gMap view.**

**[Demo without any JS involved](http://jsbin.com/aJiFOJE/1/edit)**

```
  <input type="checkbox" id="toggleMap"><label for="toggleMap"></label>
  <div id="gMap"></div>
```

```
#toggleMap{
  display:none;
}
#toggleMap + label{
  cursor:pointer;
  display:inline-block;
  width:15px;
  height:15px;
  background:url('http://i.imgur.com/wEVjlgD.gif');
  background-position: 0 -15px;
}
#toggleMap:checked + label{
   background-position: 0 0;
}

#gMap{
  background:#eee;
  width:300px;
  height:100px;
  transition:0.3s;
}
#toggleMap:checked ~ #gMap{
  height:400px;
}
```